# Perm function does not count numbers bigger than 99

Tags: c, sorting

I need to read from standard input the number N of
natural numbers to analyze. The program must then read these N
numbers and print on one line of standard output the number of those that can,
by shifting the figures in their record to be converted into one of the others
numbers read.

Example:
Keyboard input:

`6`
`25 21 10242 42210 52 24021`

Output:
`5`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long long int cache;

int cmp(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( * (int * ) a - * (int * ) b);
}

int main() {
    int n, i, j, count_equals = 0;
    char num[22];
    scanf("%d", & n);
    cache * A = (cache * ) malloc(n * sizeof(cache));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", num);
        qsort(num, strlen(num), sizeof(char), cmp);
        for (A[i] = num[--j] - '0'; --j >= 0; A[i] = A[i] * 10 + (num[j] - '0'));
    }
    qsort(A, n, sizeof(cache), cmp);
    for (j = 0, i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (A[i] == A[i - 1]) { 
            count_equals++;
        } else if (count_equals) {
            j += ++count_equals, count_equals = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count_equals) {
        j += ++count_equals;
    } 
    free(A);
    printf("%d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem: it is not getting/counting the longer numbers, also the qsort() maybe not the best solution here.

What do u suggest ?

Comment: Why should the answer be 5? After you sort the numbers, you have `10224 10224 10224 12  25 25`. `A[1] == A[0]`, `A[2] == A[1]`, and `A[4] == A[3]`. That's only 3.

Comment: 6 is the numbers count - mb for not adding the last number - havent slept in a while

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same comparison function for `char` and `cache` arrays. The comparison function needs to cast the `void*` arguments to their actual types.

```
int cmp_char(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( * (char * ) a - * (char * ) b);
}

int cmp_cache(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( * (cache * ) a - * (cache * ) b);
}
```

Then use the correct one for each call to `qsort()`

```
qsort(num, strlen(num), sizeof(char), cmp_char);
qsort(A, n, sizeof(cache), cmp_cache);
```

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't think you're counting duplicates the way you want. If you have 3 copies of the same number, you only count it as 2, because you're just counting the second occurrence in each pair.

Comment: i count like this:
 25 
10242
 42210
 52 
24021, so they are 5

Comment: But in your `for` loop you only count when `A[i] == A[i-1]`. So you don't count the first one in each set of duplicates.